# Google app engine datastore tag cloud with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tag-cloud

We have some unstructured textual data in our app engine datastore. I wanted to create a 'one off' tag cloud of one property on a subset of the datastore objects. After a look around, I can't see any framework that will allow me to do this without writing it myself.

The way I had in mind was:

- Write a map (as in map reduce) function to go over every object of the particular type in a datastore,
- Split the text string into words
- For each word increment a counter
- Use the final counts to generate the tag cloud with some third party software (offline - any suggestions here welcome)

As I've never done this before, I was wandering if firstly there is some framework around that does this for me (*please*) of if not am I approaching it in the right way. i.e please feel free to point out gaping holes in the plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Feed TagCloud](http://code.google.com/p/feed-tagcloud-appengine/) and [PyTagCloud](https://github.com/atizo/PyTagCloud) are two possibilities.

- [Feed TagCloud Generator Gadget for
  Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/p/feed-tagcloud-appengine/) might fit your
  needs.  Unfortunately, it's
  undocumented.  Fortunately it's
  rather simple, though I'm not sure
  how well-suited it is to your needs.

  It operates on a feed, and appears
  to be somewhat flexible, so if you
  have an feed of your site, it might
  not be too much trouble to
  integrate, though all processing
  will be online.
- [PyTagCloud](https://github.com/atizo/PyTagCloud) is also worth a
  look.  You'll be able to do the
  processing offline, and it generates
  rather handsome clouds.

  All you'll have to do to get this
  working, is export your datastore;
  the counts and splitting will be
  done for you, as PyTagCloud can
  operate on text files.  Following
  the instructions in the App Engine
  docs about [Uploading and
  Downloading Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) will show you
  how to export the datastore to your
  local machine.  You'll want to write
  an "Exporter Class", and have
  PyTagCloud operate on the output.

---

If you decide to roll your own, you probably want to skip the online processing and use the offline method of [Uploading and Downloading Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) above, unless you want a dynamically-updated cloud.  Iterating over your entire data store, and doing online counts is the most annoying and expensive part of the task.  It only makes sense to do this if you want or need a dynamic tag-cloud.  As above, I'd recommend writing an "Exporter Class", and operating on that locally.